# How to write a bash script that traps SIGTERM and kills the process and all sub-processes immediately

Tags: bash, signals

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
#WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE?
sleep 60 # this is for testing
#java ... | logger # this is what will be in the real script
```

I want to be able to kill myscript and all it's sub-processes by sending myscript a SIGTERM:

```
$ kill -s SIGTERM 5929
```

When I run it I see in `ps fuxa`:

```
me  3640  0.0  0.1 108416  2100 pts/2    Ss   09:38   0:00  \_ /bin/bash
me  5929  0.0  0.0 106060  1348 pts/2    S+   11:21   0:00      \_ /bin/bash myscript
me  5930  0.0  0.0 100908   604 pts/2    S+   11:21   0:00          \_ sleep 60
```

I tried numerous trap lines from different answers I found:

```
#trap 'echo hello' SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
#trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
#trap "trap - SIGTERM && kill -- -$$" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
```

I used the 1st one for debugging. What I experience is that I send the SIGTERM (or even more than one), and nothing happens. When I press `Ctrl+C`, myscript stops, and it writes "hello" number of times. So this confirms me that the way I am sending the TERM signal is correct, and it is received, but still I did not achieve my goal: to stop myscript immediately. I got the same results with the other 2 trap lines.

Comment: I think you mix it with SIGKILL. I did trap TERM, because without the trap line the script exits immediately when I sent the signal, while with the trap 'echo hello' SIGTERM it does not exit, and it prints hello, just not right away

Comment: Could the sleep be the problem? Any traps you have in place would not be executed before sleep has ended (for more on this, see [this question in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694818/interrupt-sleep-in-bash-with-a-signal-trap)).

Comment: @SamiLaine, interesting, I'll have a try tomorrow with my original code (java instead of sleep)